# Why does the root never change and why am I getting a bad access error?

Tags: c++, binary-tree, avl-tree

I'm working on an assignment to create a Self Ordering Binary Search Tree what re-organizes itself every time a duplicate element tries to be inserted into the tree. I'm having a few errors that I need help solving.

First, the root of the tree never changes (which i'm assuming the problem is in the RotateLeft or RotateRight methods) I have a sample file that I'm reading in and when walking through the code, it seems to organize everything accordingly but when the first duplicate comes in, the root never gets changed to the now higher priority node.

The second error I'm getting is a BAD ACCESS ERROR (I've noted where it is in the code below) which I'm guessing is also from one of those Rotate methods.

```
#ifndef SelfOrganizingTree_SOBTree_h
#define SelfOrganizingTree_SOBTree_h

#include "BinaryNode.h"
#include "bst.h"


template <class T>
class BinaryNode;

template <class T>
class SOBTree: public BinarySearchTree<T> {
public:
    SOBTree();
    void insert( const T& x );
    void remove( const T& x );
    bool isEmpty() const;
    void printTree() const;
    int reportComparisonCount();
    double reportCPUTime();


private:
    void insert( const T & x, BinaryNode<T> * & t , BinaryNode<T> * & rootNode);
    void RotateRight(BinaryNode<T> * & root );
    void RotateLeft(BinaryNode<T> * & root );
    void printTree(BinaryNode<T> *t) const;
    BinaryNode<T> *root;
    void balance (BinaryNode<T> * & root);

};

template <class T >
SOBTree<T> ::  SOBTree()
{
    root = NULL; 
}

/**
 * Insert x into the tree
 */
template <class T >
void SOBTree<T > ::  insert( const T & x )
{
    insert( x, root , root);
}

/**
 * Internal method to insert into a subtree.
 * x is the item to insert.
 * t is the node that roots the subtree.
 * Set the new root of the subtree.
 */
template <class T>
void SOBTree<T> ::  insert( const T & x, BinaryNode<T> * & t , BinaryNode<T> * & rootNode)
{
   // BinaryNode<T> *current = t;
    if( t == NULL ){
        t = new BinaryNode<T>( x, NULL, NULL, rootNode );
        //cout << t->element << endl;
        t->priority++;
    }
    else if( x < t->element ){
        //cout << "left" << endl;
        insert( x, t->left , t);
    }
    else if( t->element < x ){
        //cout << "right" << endl;
        insert( x, t->right , t);
    }
    else{
        //cout << "match found" << endl;
        t->priority++;  // Duplicate; rotate right or left if priority is higher than the root
        balance(t);
    }
}

template <class T>
void SOBTree<T>::balance (BinaryNode<T> * & rootN){

    cout << "root: " << root->element << endl;
    if (rootN->parent && rootN->priority > rootN->parent->priority) { //THIS IS WHERE THE BAD ACCESS ERROR IS BEING THROWN
        if (rootN->parent->left == rootN) {

            RotateLeft(rootN->parent);
            balance(rootN->parent);

        }else if (rootN->parent->right == rootN){

            RotateRight(rootN->parent); 
            balance(rootN->parent);

        }
    }

}


template <class T>
void
SOBTree<T>::RotateLeft(BinaryNode<T> * & rootN) {
    /*
     Let P be Q's left child.
     Set P to be the new root.
     Set Q's left child to be P's right child.
     Set P's right child to be Q.
     */

    BinaryNode<T> * oldRoot = rootN;

    // perform rotation
    rootN = rootN->left;
    oldRoot->left = rootN->right;
    rootN->right= oldRoot;

}


template <class T>
void
SOBTree<T>::RotateRight(BinaryNode<T> * & rootN) {
    /*
     Let Q be P's right child.
     Set Q to be the new root.
     Set P's right child to be Q's left child.
     Set Q's left child to be P.
     */

   BinaryNode<T> * oldRoot = rootN;

    // perform rotation
    rootN = rootN->right;
    oldRoot->right = rootN->left;
    rootN->left = oldRoot;

}

template <class T>
bool SOBTree<T> ::  isEmpty( ) const
{
    return root == NULL;
}

/**
 * Print the tree contents in sorted order.
 */
template <class T>
void SOBTree<T> ::  printTree(  ) const
{
    if( isEmpty( ) )
        cout << "Empty tree" << endl;
    else
        printTree( root );
}

template <class T>
void SOBTree<T> ::  printTree( BinaryNode<T> *t ) const
{
    if( t != NULL )
    {

        printTree( t->left );
        cout << t->element << endl;
        printTree( t->right );
    }else
        return;
}



#endif
```

---

Here is the code for the BinaryNode struct:

```
template <class Type>
class BinarySearchTree;     //forward declaration so BinaryNode knows about BinarySearchTree

template <class Type>
class BinaryNode{
public:
    Type element;
    BinaryNode<Type>* left;
    BinaryNode<Type>* right;
    BinaryNode<Type>* parent;
    int priority;

    BinaryNode( Type theElement, BinaryNode *lt, BinaryNode* rt, BinaryNode *par = NULL, int pri = 0) :
          element(theElement), left(lt), right(rt) ,  parent(par), priority(pri)
    { }

    friend  class BinarySearchTree<Type>;
};
```

Does anyone see anything that I could change to help out?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (rootN->parent && rootN->priority > rootN->parent->priority) {
```

Either `rootN` or `rootN->parent` is `NULL` or an otherwise invalid pointer.